# Some labels are not shown in a rotated atlas object (QGIS 3.28.8)

Tags: qgis, mapping, atlas, rotate

I have a problem that some labels from polygons are not shown in my atlas when the map is rotated. If I switch the map rotation off all labels are placed just fine. I created the atlas objects with the plugin PolyStrip. For rotationg the map I entered this formula: `(main_angle (@atlas_geometry)-90)*-1`

I have attached two screenshots

Map rotation deactivated:
[image: map rotation deactivated]

Map rotation activated. The label is missing in the upper left hand corner
[image: map rotation activated]

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two label-settings seem relevant:

1. The `Show all labels for this layer` option.
2. The `Placement` option.

In **Layer properties**|**Labels**|**Rendering**|**Label options** there is a checkbox named: `Show all labels for this layer`. Turning this on will force the display of the label, even if it collides with other labels or features. This may not always be desirable. In the example images, one label disappears because it collides with a polygon. So turning this option on might place labels in the wrong polygon.

In **Layer properties**|**Labels**|**Placement**, look at the `General settings`. If you are using a `Placement` option like *`Around Centroid`* or *`Offset from Centroid`* labels are only placed in one specific location. You could opt to change the `Placement` to *`Free`*. That way the algorithm is allowed to consider nicer label locations.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your reply. Hinting that "Around Centroid" and "Offset from Centroid" are always in specific locations did the trick. I opted for the placement setting "Horizontal" and now it almost looks the way I intended, except that the labels are now placed right on the edge of the atlas object. Not perfect but absolutely acceptable.

Comment: @Martin, if this answer helped you don't forget to mark your question as accepted to help others find similar answers in the future!